# Unable to call object method

Tags: java, methods

I'm working on an android app. That uses a 'datepicker' as part of a data entry form. I've written a getter method  `"onDateSet"` to return data from the object but i'm unable to call the method from the instance of the class.

line: `datePicker.getSelectedDate();` I'm getting a 'method cannot be resolved' error
I get the same message when I try and access the variable directly. `datePicker.selecteddate`

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
    int selectedDate;
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        selectedDate = day+month+year;
    }
    public int getSelectedDate() {
        return selectedDate;
    }

}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View view) {
    DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
    datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    int output = datePicker.getSelectedDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
```

You mean:

```
DatePickerFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
```

This is because your methods are members of your subclassed `DatePickerFragment`, not of the base class `DialogFragment`.

Essentially, when you refer to an object through its base type, the compiler only knows about the methods the base type declares. It has no way of knowing that an arbitrary `DialogFragment` is actually a `DatePickerFragment` (or any other derived type).

An alternative, if you *know* it is a `DatePickerFragment`, is to explicitly cast `datePicker` to a `DatePickerFragment`:

```
DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
...
int output = ((DatePickerFragment)datePicker).getSelectedDate();
```

This, of course, will fail with a `ClassCastException` if `datePicker` isn't actually a `DatePickerFragment`.

Comment: Thank you. The [API guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) example uses a dialogFragment. I've included a cast and now it's working.

Comment: @DavidFinder Ah, I can see the source of your confusion there. That example is intentionally kept simple, you sort of went beyond the scope of it when you tried to actually call one of the new methods that the derived class was declaring (it would have been equivalent to attempting to call `newFragment.onTimeSet()` in the example).